# How should I use mangle option in uglifyjs?

Tags: javascript, minify, uglifyjs

When running the following command:

```
echo "let demo = 3; console.log(demo);" | uglifyjs --compress --mangle
```

I would expect the following output:

```
let a=3;console.log(a);
```

Instead, I get:

```
let demo=3;console.log(demo);
```

Therefore, I don't understand how I should use `--mangle` option. [The official documentation](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) explains how to exclude the names which shouldn't be mangled, how to mangle properties, etc., but how do I just transform the names of ordinary variables?

Or is this option doing something completely different, and I misunderstood its purpose?

Note: I'm using [uglify-es](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/tree/harmony) 3.2.2.

Comment: did you try "uglifyjs --compress --mangle --toplevel" ? should mangle everything in the top level scope

Comment: @MercyDude: nice! Please, post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So I looked at [The official documentation](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2), and as you said `--mangle` is the option where you choose what not to mangle (how convenient), and figured out that you should use `--toplevel` which mangle everything in the top level scope.

Eventually it should look like that:

`uglifyjs --compress --mangle --toplevel`